# Python Programming Novice: How can I input and store 5 team names, and associate scores with them?

Tags: python

I am learning python and I have to create a python program to be used in a school tournament.  I know how to input and print names using the input and print command. I know how to add numbers using the + key. What I get stuck with is how would I enter 5 names e.g. teamA, Team B, TeamC, TeamD and Team E. store them so I could call them back and add point scores to them for events they carried out.  At then end printing them out.

```
n = int(input("Enter number of teams : "))
for i in range(n):
    name = input("Enter team name : ")
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I recommend using a loop and a dictionary. The dictionary can have `str` keys (the team name) and `int` values (the score). I recommend using Google to search for tutorials on python loops and `dict`s.

Comment: Store the names as the key in a dictionary.

Comment: outside the `for` loop create a dictionary `teams = {}` then inside your loop `teams[name] = score`

Comment: read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can save the team names to a list, or a dictionary.
here is an example with list:

```
n = int(input("Enter number of teams : "))

teams = [input(f"Enter name for team #{i+1} : ") for i in range(n)]

# input scores
scores = [input(f"Input score for team {teams[i]}: ") for i in range(n)]

# print out
[print(f"Team {teams[i]} : {scores[i]}") for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Using `print` in a list comprehension needlessly creates a new list. `for i in range(n): print(f"Team {teams[i]} : {scores[i]}")`

Comment: And parallel lists are a terrible habit to get into.

Comment: Thats very good  so how would I then add additional rounds? So this does one round but what if I had four events so have to repeat the process 4 times?   The tournament has four rounds so I need to record the scores for four different events.

Answer (score 0):

```
# the dictionary way
n = int(input("Enter number of teams : "))

teams = {input(f"Enter name for team #{i+1} : "):int(input(f"Enter score for team #{i+1}: ")) for i in range(n)}

#retrieve those saved data for later use
for team,score in teams.items():
    print(f"Score of team {team} is {score}")

# exceptions should be handled for invalid input
```

Comment: Do you really feel that a convoluted dict comprehension is a viable solution for a self-admitted novice?  Especially given the fundamental nature of the question?

Comment: And *two* answers?  Just update / revise one.  No need for two.